# Javascript setTimeout() and window functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resize, settimeout

The following JavaScript code runs in chrome, and results in the "background" window being resized to the my specifications:

```
var background;
function play () {
    var w  = screen.width;
    var h  = screen.height;
    if( !background || background.closed ) background = window.open("background.html", "It's a pop-up!", "top="+ 100 +",left="+ 770 +",width="+ w/3 +",height="+ h/3 +",location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no");
    background.resizeTo(w,724);
}
```

When I try to delay the resize function, however, the code breaks. Why does calling `setTimeout("background.resizeTo(w,724)",10000)` have no visible result?

Comment: Could be a scope issue. Does `setTimeout(function() { background.resizeTo(w,724); },10000)` work? I hope you know that `10000` are 10 seconds. So you don't see any immediate changes. *Edit:* Ah yes, @John is right, the `w` is the issue. Still, instead of passing a string, you should pass a function.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit to the post because it invalidates the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
setTimeout(function(){background.resizeTo(w,724);},10000);
```

You should pass a function. This is the proper solution, don't ever rely on passing a string as a 'function' when using `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, it's slower because it has to be evaluated and it just isn't right.

Furthermore you may have problems with the scope (like in your example). Your code would only work if both, `background` and `w` are *global*. We don't know about `background`, but `w` is definitely only local to `play`. Passing a function which closes over those variables (a *closure*) instead of a string, solves this problem.

For more info about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax

Comment: Passing a string is valid too but bad practice. *"the latter method shouldn't even work per the ECMAScript specification"*: `setTimeout` is **not** part of the specification. `window` is a host object, which are not covered by the specification.

Comment: FWIW, properties that have to be implemented by the global object [can be found here](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.1). But `setTimeout` and friends are not part of it.

Comment: srry i dint follow your last stmt.. what are you saying is incorrect?

Comment: Your statement about the ECMAScript specification not allowing (mentioning) `setTimeout` to take a string was not correct because `setTimeout` is not part of the specification.

Comment: well setTimeout per say might not be defined but there must be something in there about callback functions

Answer (score -1):

Because the entire statement is basically eval'd and w has no meaning anymore.

try this:

```
setTimeout('background.resizeTo('+w+',724',10000);
```

Comment: Correct, but instead of passing a string, you really should pass a function.

Comment: An anonymous closure out in the wild isn't too much better than an eval at the end of the day.